# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Sujata_Selenium_workspace\chromedriver.exe

Tags: selenium

xception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Sujata_Selenium_workspace\chromedriver.exe
Errors is showing.

package seleniumWebdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LaunchBrowser {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Sujata_Selenium_workspace\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
}
```

}

Comment: i have created a folder in c drive and gave the path of extracted chromedrive,but its throwing above Errors.please help me out from this.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do in your question please?

Comment: Can you add complete stacktrace

Comment: HI, for launching chrome browser in seleniumm with jave i have written a program in eclipse but i am unable to launch.i am getting above errors.please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `chromedriver` does not placed in the path your defined `"C:\Sujata_Selenium_workspace\chromedriver.exe"`

Either place the `chromedriver` in the path or place it somewhere in D or E drive like

```
D:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe
```

Code like

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
```

Comment: HI,i have followed your procedure still i am getting same issue.can you please suggest me what to do

Comment: pLease add the snapshot of the location where you store chromedriver